# PowerShell to prettify multiple JSON files in one folder

Tags: json, windows, powershell, shell, loops

My goal is to prettify all the JSON files (about 70K of them) in one folder.
Say I have one folder named "juicero" and in there there are about 70K .JSON files with different names - 
a.json, b.json

This is what I tried -

```
PS> $files = Get-ChildItem C:\users\gamer\desktop\juicero\*.json
PS> $json_test = (Get-Content $files -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)
PS> foreach ($file in $files) { ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $files }
```

I thought it would iterate through the path and prettify these (pretty straight-forward logic) but for some reason, this is deleting the content of the files. If I don't iterate and just use this function on one .json file it works - so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the iteration logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work on files inside the loop, like that:

```bsh
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $content = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
  $newFilePath = $file.FullName.Replace("OldFolder","NewFolder")
  ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $content| Set-Content $newFilePath
}
```

Notice that I'm putting output files into new folder, for easier debugging in case any issues.

---

There's one more issue with your code. Here you're converting all the files at once:

```bsh
$json_test = (Get-Content $files -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

However, later on, PowerShell has no information about source file name (file name is not included in `$json_test`).

Comment: that makes sense - I just ran it and I'm running into issues - I'm trying to add Depth to the file but it's not working

Comment: Where can I add the -depth to the conversion?

Comment: Check the docs of cmdlets you're using and search for `-Depth`. For example [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7)